# AuditD - right usage and syntax of -q flag in rules

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, auditd

I would like to use -q flag in auditd rule, but the rule with the -q flag is not working or even added into the rules list.
I have rule like this:

```
-a always,exit -F path=/home/lukashubl/ -q /home/lukashubl/dirtest,/home/lukashubl/dirtest/bin -F perm=rwxa
```

I am using auditbeat and I am getting this error:

```
flag provided but not defined: -q accessing '0'
```

I also tried to test the rule with auditctl:

```
auditctl -a always,exit -F path=/home/lukashubl/ -q /home/lukashubl/dirtest,/home/lukashubl/dirtest/bin -F perm=rwxa
```

But when I list all rules by `auditcl -l`, the rule is not there and no error at output.

What is the right syntax and usage of -q flag in auditd rule?